# Can you become the deputy of Arkham after another player has?

Tags: arkham-horror

If someone has taken this card, is another player able to seize it from them by trading in trophies at the police station to become the deputy themselves? If so, do they take the Patrol Wagon (whether it has been discarded or not) and/or the Deputy's Revolver? It isn't clear whether this would be officially having it lost or stolen.

Comment: When you say "seize", do you mean trading it to another player as you do with items?

Comment: I mean can he go to the police station and become deputy, then take it from the other player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explicitly answered in [the FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf):

> Q: Can an investigator trade in trophies to become the Deputy if another investigator is already the Deputy (the existing Deputy would stop being Deputy)? If so, do they acquire the Patrol Wagon and/or Deputy’s Revolver if they are still in the other investigator’s possession?
>
> A: No.

Comment: I haven't read all the cards, but is there a way for a person to stop being deputy once they are? If so, can someone else then become the deputy?

Comment: @Joey It's not an item, so it can't be lost/stolen. I believe the only way you can ever stop being the deputy is if you're devoured, at which point it'd be discarded. I don't think any rules explicitly cover that, but it'd probably make sense for a new player to be able to get deputized at that point.

Comment: I suppose the fact that the faq question says "if another is already the deputy" may imply that it is "yes, if someone else is not deputy (anymore)"

Comment: @Joey It might be noteworthy (you or general) that as far as I can tell, the patrol wagon and revolver are items, so the only thing untradable is the "job" itself which basically gives money which can also be traded.  It does make sense that you cannot trade/buyout the capability not to be arrested and anything else that comes with the title=)

Comment: My previous comment erroneously said you cannot be arrested, sorry.  I was thinking about curfew doesn't affect the deputy.  Sorry about that.  I cannot edit so am adding instead, rather than directing another @.